# プロファイルの「自分について」にフォーマッティングバグ

Tags: バグ, 再現性なし, デザイン

「自分について」が現在空白なら、

> (あなたの［*自分について*］は現在空白です)
>
> 編集するにはここをクリック

が表示されているけど、フォーマティングが何となく間違うと思う。

> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここで`(あなたの［_自分について_］は現在空白です)`が大丈夫だけど、問題は「自分について」です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

バグは既に修正されました。

> [image: 修正されました]